# Symbolab solves $0=8a-10000/a^2$ and $0=8a-\frac{10000}{a^2}$ differently. Aren't the equations the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the both formulas - in my opinion they are exactly the same:

(A):
[image: 0=8a-10000/a^2]

(A): https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/0%3D8a%20-%2010000%2Fa%5E%7B2%7D?or=input

(B): [image: 0=8a-10000/a^2]

(B): https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/0%3D8a-%5Cfrac%7B10000%7D%7Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7D?or=input

The result of (A) is correct, but (B) is wrong.

I can't get it. It's me or is Symbolab doing some weird stuff?

Comment: (A) is solving $0 = \frac{8a-10000}{a^2}$; is that really what you want? I would read the image text as $0 = 8a - \left(\frac{10000}{a^2}\right)$, and I think most others would too. The latter is what (B) is solving.

Answer (score 3):

For some unknown reason, the first one is taken to be
$$
0 = \frac{8a - 10000}{a^2},
$$
which is incorrect. I agree that your notation is equivalent to
$$
0 = 8a - \frac{10000}{a^2}.
$$

Interestingly, using their own interface (which substitutes $\div$ for $/$) I got the same error:
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/0%3D8a%20-%2010000%5Cdiv%20a%5E%7B2%7D?or=input

Here is what the relevant section in the screen looks like. It is noteworthy that at the top, they suggest to solve the correct equation instead. Apparently they think it is user input error and try to second-guess the user's original intent...

[image]